# Is there a way to create a GitHub bot/probot to review branch policy on my repo?

Tags: javascript, github, github-actions

I want to make sure that repos have a branch policy with certain options turned on, I want to automate this and have been looking into creating a GitHub probot to help with this but I just can’t figure out how I will be able to review a repo’s branch policy or if that is even possible.
Another thought I had was to create a GitHub action and run that just in case a bot may not have those permissions.

Could anyone point me in the right direction, I’m just starting out in my programming journey, I have a good understanding it’s just this is new territory for me.

Comment: Bot or not, if you can access the options anything/anyone with the session or credentials could act on your behalf so this could be done without API but for ease use the API if it's included and allows these actions you speak of.

Comment: Otherwise, we'd just take a copy of our headers we sent github and send it in front of any of our requests and we'll manually dig to find the get/post requests we want. Some developer console (network) lurking for that. Many will use axios for sending requests/receiving.

Comment: [Settings probot](https://probot.github.io/apps/settings/) might be of help. It doesn’t check the already set settings but you can set use it to set repo settings in one config file and reuse on the repos.